# Приложение не работает при запуске из сетевой шары

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Есть приложение, работающее с SOAP, приложение расположено на сетевом диске.

Все ПК под управлением Windows 7 SP 1, на 2х ПК из 4х приложение запускается и работает нормально. На 2х других приложение запускается, но при попытке обращения к сети валится с ошибкой:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Ошибка при создания веб-посредника, указанного в разделе конфигурации 'system.net/defaultProxy'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Получен недопустимый аргумент

Но в config-файле секции `system.net` нет совсем.

Если в конфиг добавить строчки:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="false" useDefaultCredentials="false" />
</system.net>
```

то приложение валится с ошибкой:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: Прослушивание на http://... не выполняла ни одна конечная точка, которая могла бы принять сообщение. Среди прочих причин это могло быть вызвано неправильным адресом или действием SOAP. Подробнее см. в описании InnerException (если имеется). ---> System.Net.WebException: Базовое соединение закрыто: Невозможно соединиться с удаленным сервером. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Получен недопустимый аргумент

на 3х из 4х ПК (на одном продолжает работать нормально)

Если приложение перенести из сетевого диска на локальный, то оно начинает работать нормально на всех ПК, но этот способ мне не подходит по независящим от меня причинам

Переустанавливал .NET 4.0 - не помогло, натыкался [этот комментарий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194823/exception-when-running-net-4-0-application-from-network-share#comment23161617_16194823) и ставил указанный патч - не помогло, установил на один из тех двух ПК .NET 4.5.2 - не помогло, установил на второй .NET 4.7.1 - не помогло.

Подозреваю, что это как-то связано с безопасностью Windows и система считает приложение из сетевой шары недостаточно надежным для таких операций, как доступ в сеть, но на 2х других ПК оно же работает нормально, значит это должно как-то где-то настраиваться?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74503/discussion-on-question-by--nop-------).

Comment: У меня сейчас та же проблема. после обновления windows все приложения не из windows store, что требуют интернет перестали работать. выводится ровно то же сообщение - "ошибка при создании веб-посредника, указанного в разделе конфигурации 'system.net/defaultProxy'. как-то связано с net.framework, я понял, но ничего изменить не получается, откатил обновления, удалил их полностью, переустановил net.framework, восстановил пк по точке восстановления...
в нет фреймворк есть файл конфиг, его правил - ничего. в самих приложениях в конфига файлах = добавлял ту же строку, что и автор - ничего не пойму..